# Envio de dados byte[] socket

Tags: java, socket, byte

estou com um problema a uns dias que não consigo resolver.

Possuo uma conexão socket e estou testando assinatura nas mensagens, possuo um objeto `Mensagem` que contem `String mensagem`, `String assinatura` e `PublicKey chavePublica`, no meu cliente eu peço uma entrada de texto com o Scanner, depois monto o objeto de Mensagem que irei enviar atraves de `socketClient.write(mensagem)` tudo funciona como esperado exceto pela assinatura, segue o fluxo:

Byte[] -> Base64 Encode -> String -> Socket Write -> **Get Bytes** -> Base64 Decode -> Byte[]

Ou seja, minha assinatura está em `byte[]`, mantenho no mesmo tipo ao fazer encode 64, OK. Após isso utilizo `new String(assinatura, "ISO-8859-1")` e a assinatura vira:

`MCwCFE2V4wamcL/3FpjXXjHcEXcNWsohAhQTVoOLVmaxkazBgRsw0ZDGi3Mzkg==`

O socket recebe ok, porém, quando tento voltar dessa `String` para `byte[]` novamente, não é o mesmo `byte[]`, o problema não é do socket pois mesmo na mesma classe tenho esse problema, eu transformo em `String` mas não retorna igual para `byte[]`. Alguem pode me ajudar?

### Transformando em String

`byte[] assinatura = cripto.assinar(mensagem);
byte[] assinatura64 = Base64.encodeBase64(assinatura); //Byte[] to Byte[] 64Encode
String assinaturaStr = new String(assinatura64, "ISO-8859-1"); //Byte[] to String`

### Retornando para Byte

`String assinatura = mensagem.getAssinatura(); //Retorna a String correta assinada
byte[] assinaturaBytes = assinatura.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
byte[] assinaturaBytes64 = Base64.decodeBase64(assinaturaBytes);`

Comment: Adicione o trecho relevante que faz a conversão do código.

Comment: Conteudo editado, esta da forma que faco as conversoes, nem a leitura do assinaturaBytes nem do assinaturaBytes64 é igual a assinatura que gerei.